# Rails 4 - Updating Specific Attributes in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a marketplace app (rails 4) where sellers can list items to sell. I have a seller profile form where users enter some details about their brand.

I'm not able to get the record to update with user inputs. The form submits without any error but the model is not updated.

Code below. Demo at http://mktdemo.herokuapp.com/seller/18 (login: test@test.com / pwd: test1234)

route:

```
match "/seller/:id", to: "users#sellerprofile", via: [:get, :put], as: :sellerprofile
```

my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: sellerprofile_path(id: current_user.id), method: :put, html: { :class => 'edit_profile', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :your_story %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.text_area :profilestory, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profile_image %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.file_field :profileimage, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>

 <% end %>
```

user_controller:

```
def sellerprofile
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @user.update_attributes(:profilestory => params[:profilestory], :profileimage => params[:profileimage])
end
```

For the image, I'm using paperclip and have the has_attached... code in my model.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my user_params in controller:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:bankaccname, :profileimage, :profilestory)
  end
```

When I use `@user.update(user_params)` in the sellerprofile method, I get a `params :user not found error`. This error occurs when I load the form (not on submit). Error is in the line `params.require(:user)`

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the update method. I'm using this for another form that takes in some bank account data so I'm not sure if I can modify this for the profile form.

```
def update
    @user.attributes = user_params
    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => user_params["bankaccname"], 
        :type => "individual",              
        :bank_account => token              
        )                                   

      @user.recipient = recipient.id

     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the rails version in your app? If it's >=4 then you need to use strong parameters

Comment: Rails 4. I have user_params defined but when I use update(user_params) I get an error saying params :user not found.

Comment: Can you post your code, logs when you submit form and full error?

Comment: What do you see when you print/inspect params in your controller?

Comment: Updated with user_params info.

Comment: @Moosa you have your form in which action? Can you post that method

Comment: It's put. It's in the form_for code in the post.

Comment: @Moosa i'm asking about the controller method. Can you post the your controller action which renders your form :)

Comment: I think there is something weird with the ":id", you use the same symbol for two different things.  One in the /match/:id and the other on the form_for tag ... try making them unique

Comment: @Mandeep You mean the update method? I'm not pointing to this because I'm using it for another form. Not sure if I can modify to use for the profile form. Updated post.

Comment: @Moosa Are you rendering your form in update action? I'm asking which action in your controllers renders this form `<%= form_for(@user, url: sellerprofile_path(id: current_user.id), method: :put, html: { :class => 'edit_profile', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>` because your question says `This error occurs when I load the form (not on submit)` so need to see that action.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But when I change the sellerprofile method to not use user_params(like in post), then the form loads.

Comment: @Moosa well what is the url for your form?

Comment: /seller/:id - route is in post. ID is the user id.

Comment: @Moosa writing my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your question, it says:

> When I use @user.update(user_params) in the sellerprofile method, I get a params :user not found error. This error occurs when I load the form (not on submit)

*This line tells us that there is **something wrong in the action where your form is rendered. I mean the url you hit in browsers address bar to display your form***

And in your comment you told me that the url for rendering your form is `/seller/:id` and now lets look at your form code

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: sellerprofile_path(id: current_user.id), method: :put, html: { :class => 'edit_profile', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Notice the url used in the form? You are using the same action to render your form and then after submitting form it'll again take you to same action which is wrong. You should make two different routes. One to render your form and other one to create it. To explain it further, if you look at your code

```
 def sellerprofile
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.update_attributes(user_params) 
 end
```

So when you hit `/seller/:id` ***it takes you to sellerprofile method and hence code inside your sellerprofile method fires up and it tries to update your user because of this line `@user.update_attributes(user_params)` but there are no user_params as you didn't submit any form so you get a params :user not found errorr***

**Fix:**

***Just make two different routes, one to render your form and another one to create your record:***

```
match "/seller/:id/new", to: "users#sellernew", via: [:get], as: :sellernewprofile
match "/seller/:id", to: "users#sellerprofile", via: [:put], as: :sellerprofile
```

Comment: Great! I had to add a blank sellernew method and create the html files per those names but it works! Now when form submits, it redirects to sellerprofile.html which is like a profile updated message. Instead of a redirect, how do I just show a notice on the form page?

Comment: @Moosa sorry didn't get you?

Comment: when form submits, how do I stay on same form page with a flash msg saying "profile updated"

Comment: @Moosa if you want to stay at same page then use ajax for it. Submit your form remotely and then in your js add a new div which will behave like a flash